# Format Cell Values in an Infragistics UltraWinGrid

Tags: formatting, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have an Infragistics UltraWinGrid bound to a data source, and one of the columns in that data source contains boolean values.  I have the `Style` property for the column set to `Edit` so that it will display text instead of a checkbox.  However, instead of displaying the values `True` or `False`, I want it to display `Yes` or `No`.

How do I format the value of the cell to display Yes or No for a boolean value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a ValueList and set the ValueList property of the column

```
private void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
{
    ValueList vl=new ValueList();
    vl.ValueListItems.Add(true, "Yes");
    vl.ValueListItems.Add(false, "No");
    e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["ColumnBoolean"].ValueList=vl;
}
```